# How to set a imageview like a hexagon in ios exactly below

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I need to give bounds of an `imageView` like a hexagon. I've searched in Stack Overflow and get the code, but it not exactly satisfy the need.

[image: Please click here.this is my example imageview]

Comment: Mask your imageView's layer with CAShapeLayer, which has hexagon as a path.

Comment: ok, can you please give a sample code for this?

Comment: Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: Please give a sample in Objective-C

Comment: please look at my answer.

Comment: hi dennis, in that example am not exactly got the same result, i got the flat corner on the upper and lower side and the sharp corner came in left and right side of your example. am trying to rotate it but am not !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works for me:

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
maskLayer.frame = img_profilepic.bounds;

CGFloat width = img_profilepic.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = img_profilepic.frame.size.height;
CGFloat hPadding = width * 1 / 8 / 2;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img_profilepic.frame.size);
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(width/2, 0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width - hPadding, height / 4)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width - hPadding, height * 3 / 4)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width / 2, height)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(hPadding, height * 3 / 4)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(hPadding, height / 4)];
[path closePath];
[path closePath];
[path fill];
[path stroke];

maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

img_profilepic.layer.mask = maskLayer;
img_profilepic.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_picture"];
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here is an example of how to do it.

First, create a category on `UIBezierPath`:

**Objective-C**:

.h file:

```
@import UIKit.UIBezierPath;

@interface UIBezierPath (Additions)

+ (UIBezierPath * _Nullable)bezierPathWithSquare:(CGRect)square numberOfSides:(NSUInteger)numberOfSides cornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "UIBezierPath+Additions.h"

@implementation UIBezierPath (Additions)

+ (UIBezierPath *)bezierPathWithSquare:(CGRect)square numberOfSides:(NSUInteger)numberOfSides cornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius
{
    if ( CGRectGetWidth(square) != CGRectGetHeight(square) )
    {
        return nil;
    }

    CGFloat squareWidth = CGRectGetWidth(square);

    if ( numberOfSides == 0 || cornerRadius < 0.0 || 2.0 * cornerRadius > squareWidth || CGRectIsInfinite(square) || CGRectIsEmpty(square) || CGRectIsNull(square) )
    {
        return nil;
    }

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];

    CGFloat theta = 2.0 * M_PI / numberOfSides;
    CGFloat offset = cornerRadius * tan(0.5 * theta);

    CGFloat length = squareWidth - path.lineWidth;
    if ( numberOfSides % 4 != 0 )
    {
        length = length * cos(0.5 * theta);
    }

    CGFloat sideLength = length * tan(0.5 * theta);

    CGFloat p1 = squareWidth / 2.0 + sideLength / 2.0 - offset;
    CGFloat p2 = squareWidth - (squareWidth - length) / 2.0;
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(p1, p2);
    CGFloat angle = M_PI;
    [path moveToPoint:point];

    for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfSides; i++ )
    {
        CGFloat x1 = point.x + ( sideLength - offset * 2.0 ) * cos(angle);
        CGFloat y1 = point.y + ( sideLength - offset * 2.0 ) * sin(angle);

        point = CGPointMake(x1, y1);
        [path addLineToPoint:point];

        CGFloat centerX = point.x + cornerRadius * cos(angle + M_PI_2);
        CGFloat centerY = point.y + cornerRadius * sin(angle + M_PI_2);
        CGPoint center = CGPointMake(centerX, centerY);
        CGFloat radius = cornerRadius;
        CGFloat startAngle = angle - M_PI_2;
        CGFloat endAngle = angle + theta - M_PI_2;

        [path addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
        point = path.currentPoint;
        angle += theta;
    }

    [path closePath];

    return path;
}

@end
```

Then, your view controller's implementation will look like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UIBezierPath+Additions.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupImageViewHexagonMask];
}

- (void)setupImageViewHexagonMask
{
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithSquare:self.imageView.bounds numberOfSides:6 cornerRadius:20.0];
    CAShapeLayer *maskingLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskingLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

    self.imageView.layer.mask = maskingLayer;
}

@end
```

**Swift 2**:

Create an extension on `UIBezierPath`

```
import UIKit

/** Additions Extends UIBezierPath

*/
extension UIBezierPath {

    convenience init?(square: CGRect, numberOfSides: UInt, cornerRadius: CGFloat) {

        guard CGRectGetWidth(square) == CGRectGetHeight(square) else {

            return nil
        }

        let squareWidth = CGRectGetWidth(square)

        guard numberOfSides > 0 && cornerRadius >= 0.0 && 2.0 * cornerRadius < squareWidth && !CGRectIsInfinite(square) && !CGRectIsEmpty(square) && !CGRectIsNull(square) else {

            return nil
        }

        self.init()

        // how much to turn at every corner
        let theta =  CGFloat(2.0 * M_PI) / CGFloat(numberOfSides)

        // offset from which to start rounding corners
        let offset: CGFloat = cornerRadius * CGFloat(tan( theta / 2.0 ))

        var length = squareWidth - lineWidth
        if( numberOfSides % 4 != 0){
            length = length * cos(theta / 2.0)
        }

        let sideLength = length * CGFloat(tan(theta / 2.0))

        // start drawing ap 'point' in lower right corner
        let p1 = squareWidth / 2.0 + sideLength / 2.0 - offset
        let p2 = squareWidth - ((squareWidth - length) / 2.0)
        var point = CGPointMake(CGFloat(p1), CGFloat(p2))
        var angle = CGFloat(M_PI)
        moveToPoint(point)

        // draw the sides around rounded corners of the polygon
        for ( var i: UInt = 0; i < numberOfSides; i++){
            let x1 = CGFloat(point.x) + ((sideLength - offset * 2.0) * CGFloat(cos(angle)))
            let y1 = CGFloat(point.y) + ((sideLength - offset * 2.0) * CGFloat(sin(angle)))

            point = CGPointMake(CGFloat(x1), CGFloat(y1))
            addLineToPoint(point)

            let centerX = point.x + cornerRadius * CGFloat(cos(angle + CGFloat(M_PI_2)))
            let centerY = point.y + cornerRadius * CGFloat(sin(angle + CGFloat(M_PI_2)))
            let center = CGPointMake(CGFloat(centerX), CGFloat(centerY))
            let radius:CGFloat = CGFloat(cornerRadius)
            let startAngle = CGFloat(angle) - CGFloat(M_PI_2)
            let endAngle = CGFloat(angle) + CGFloat(theta) - CGFloat(M_PI_2)

            addArcWithCenter(center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            point = currentPoint
            angle += theta

        }

        closePath()
    }
}
```

Example view controller's implementation:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        applyHexagonMask()
    }

    private func applyHexagonMask() {

        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(square: imageView.bounds, numberOfSides: 6, cornerRadius: 10.0)

        let maskingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskingLayer.path = maskPath?.CGPath

        imageView.layer.mask = maskingLayer
    }
}
```

**Swift 4**:

```
import UIKit

extension UIBezierPath {

    convenience init?(square: CGRect, numberOfSides: UInt, cornerRadius: CGFloat) {

        guard square.width == square.height else { return nil }

        let squareWidth = square.width

        guard numberOfSides > 0 && cornerRadius >= 0.0 && 2.0 * cornerRadius < squareWidth && !square.isInfinite && !square.isEmpty && !square.isNull else {

            return nil
        }

        self.init()

        // how much to turn at every corner
        let theta =  2.0 * .pi / CGFloat(numberOfSides)
        let halfTheta = 0.5 * theta

        // offset from which to start rounding corners
        let offset: CGFloat = cornerRadius * CGFloat(tan(halfTheta))

        var length = squareWidth - self.lineWidth
        if numberOfSides % 4 > 0 {

            length = length * cos(halfTheta)
        }

        let sideLength = length * CGFloat(tan(halfTheta))

        // start drawing at 'point' in lower right corner
        let p1 = 0.5 * (squareWidth + sideLength) - offset
        let p2 = squareWidth - 0.5 * (squareWidth - length)
        var point = CGPoint(x: p1, y: p2)
        var angle = CGFloat.pi

        self.move(to: point)

        // draw the sides around rounded corners of the polygon
        for _ in 0..<numberOfSides {

            let x1 = CGFloat(point.x) + ((sideLength - offset * 2.0) * CGFloat(cos(angle)))
            let y1 = CGFloat(point.y) + ((sideLength - offset * 2.0) * CGFloat(sin(angle)))

            point = CGPoint(x: x1, y: y1)
            self.addLine(to: point)

            let centerX = point.x + cornerRadius * CGFloat(cos(angle + 0.5 * .pi))
            let centerY = point.y + cornerRadius * CGFloat(sin(angle + 0.5 * .pi))
            let center = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
            let startAngle = CGFloat(angle) - 0.5 * .pi
            let endAngle = CGFloat(angle) + CGFloat(theta) - 0.5 * .pi

            self.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            point = self.currentPoint
            angle += theta

        }

        self.close()
    }
}
```

Example view controller's implementation:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        applyHexagonMask()
    }

    private func applyHexagonMask() {

        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(square: imageView.bounds, numberOfSides: 6, cornerRadius: 10.0)

        let maskingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskingLayer.path = maskPath?.cgPath

        imageView.layer.mask = maskingLayer
    }
}
```

Result from playground:

[image: Result]

Enjoy.

Comment: Hi Dennis, Thank you for your answer. in this example code am not exactly got the same result i need, i got the flat corner on the upper and lower side and the sharp corner came in left and right side of your example. am trying to rotate it but am not ! please help

Comment: @IOSdeveloper, is it still actual?

Comment: I got the hexagonal from your code but in inverse format ,  flat corner on the upper and lower side and the sharp corner came in left and right side. @Dennis

Comment: @IOSdeveloper so what you need to do is to call `applyTransform:` method on created `UIBezierPath`. And pass your required rotation transform, e.g. `CGAffineTransformCreateRotation(your_rotation_angle)`

Comment: First of all this code had so many errors, second of all its generating  a small star  and not a hexagon, when i got it working. Please provide a solution in swift 4 to make a hexagon Imageview. Thanks, i would appreciate it.

Comment: @ZahurafzalMirza, I have updated the answer to swift 4. Please check if it helps you

Comment: Thanks :) IT Works perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: @DennisPashkov - This is very nice! Can you help to rotate this mask at the angle of 90